# Sometime an error occur that CI controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a codeigniter project. My website is going good but sometime an error occur that CI controller not found in core/codeigniter.php line number 234. I'm not able to find exact problem. Please provide me a valid solution. Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Here is how line number 234 looks like

```
function &get_instance()
    {
        return CI_Controller::get_instance();
    }
```

One thing that is amazing me that this error occcur sometime not quite oftenly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Neither we are able to find exact problem without knowing where and when it occurs

Comment: And what exactly does line number 1-235 look like?

Comment: OK, I'll just dig out my crystal ball and use it to look at the code you didn't provide and the logging you haven't shown.

Answer (score -2):

Check your controller name. Controller name should always start with a capital letter. As shown below.

```
Controller_name.php
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment.  Please don't answer questions unless you have an actual answer.  Also, please don't attempt to answer questions that are essentially unanswerable as it only encourages further bad questions.